# card view cardCornerRadius not visible on image its display image without corners, how to resolve?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-cardview

My project suddenly remove all corner radius from all images
I was use card view to apply radius to images but suddenly its not have any radius corner, what happen with my project? I can not find out any issue, neither change one single line in my project
check this image [image]

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_15sdp">
```

Comment: value of `@dimen/_15sdp` ?

Comment: 15.00dp I was added dimension file for all screen

Comment: I'd have a look at the `res\value\dimens` folder and/or the `dimens.xml` file or files. Is `_15sdp` still correctly defined? Do you maybe have several such XML files e.g. for portrait/landscape or for different screen resolutions and you changed the device/emulator?

Comment: its defined correctly in all files and project support only portrait mode

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I resolve this by removing two lines from AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"
```